# Prove that $\phi(p(x)) = p(a)$ is a ring isomorphism from the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}(x)$ to the ring $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ring-homomorphism

I have a proof for this, it was quite easy and straightforward, but that's the problem. It seemed too easy, I just want to make sure I didn't miss any important nuances or simplify things too greatly.

---

The full problem statement is as follows

> If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field and $a \in \mathbb{F}$ is any element then prove that $\phi: \mathbb{F}(x) \to \mathbb{F}$ defined by $\phi(p(x)) = p(a)$ is a ring homomorphism from the ring $\mathbb{F}(x)$ to the ring $\mathbb{F}$.

---

Let $p(x), p'(x) \in \mathbb{F}(x)$ then we have
$$\phi(p(x) + p'(x)) = (p(a) + p'(a)) = p(a) + p'(a) = \phi(p(x)) + \phi(p'(x))$$
$$\phi(p(x)p'(x)) = (p(a)p'(a)) = p(a)p'(a) = \phi(p(x))\phi(p'(x))$$

Essentially since $\mathbb{F}(x)$ and $\mathbb{F}$ are rings where multiplication is defined? Is it that straightforward?

Comment: If $q(x):=p(x)+p’(x)$, how do you know that $q(a) = p(a)+p’(a)$? This is the exercise.

Comment: Do you mean homomorphism instead of isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terms of your problem statement, it probably is that simple and is OK.

However IMHO it is worthwhile making a distinction between $p$, a polynomial, and $p(x)$, which is a value of a polynomial.  Then the problem would define the homomorphism by
$$\phi(p)=p(a)$$
and the proof would be
$$\phi(p+p')=(p+p')(a)=p(a)+p'(a)=\phi(p)+\phi(p')\ .$$
Depending on the approach you have taken, the reason for the middle step would either be a previously proved theorem, or the definition of polynomial addition.

Comment: Thanks for the verification @David. Regarding the distinction you brought up. What exactly would be the explicit form for $p$ versus $p(x)$ other than the explicit variable dependence? It was my understanding, from my text, that $f = f(x)$ was simply the suppression of this variable dependence. In other words, as I understood it, $f(x)$ is still a polynomial, and not a value of a polynomial, as $x$ is a variable and the definition of a polynomial is defined as a formal sum (over some variable) $$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n = \Sigma_{k = 0}^{n} a_kx^k$$ Where $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$

Comment: Are you saying there is a more subtle distinction between these $2$ or could it perhaps just be an issue of conflicting interpretation of non-standardized notation?

Comment: I think everyone would agree that $f(5)$ is not a polynomial, it is a number.  IMHO $f(x)$ is also a number - albeit an unspecified one if $x$ is unspecified.  One can define a polynomial $p$ by giving a formula for $p(x)$, but that is not the same as saying that the polynomial **is** $p(x)$.

Comment: Another issue to think about: if you say that the polynomial **is** the formula in terms of $x$, then what about $1+2x+3x^2$ and $1+2y+3y^2$?  Are they the same polynomial, or different?  Having said all this, I would add that often it's really not all that important.  I have always felt that one of the most valuable things in studying mathematics is learning when it's OK to be sloppy.